Import my year-to-date (YTD) tax statements from different US brokerage accounts, and give me a summary of it (eg "X USD in short-term gains")
I am looking for a program or web-based service that can import my year-to-date (YTD) tax statements from different US brokerage accounts, and give me a summary of it (e.g, "X USD in short-term gains, Y USD in long-term gains, Z USD in dividends").
https://www.mint.com/ and https://www.personalcapital.com/ don't seem to have this information.
No preference regarding the license, the cost or the operating system.
